# How I can use 'regex' package in python without installation?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, package

I want to use `regex` package without installation (neither using `pip` nor `python setup.py install`)

For that, I have downloaded the package and kept in the same directory of the file where I am importing `regex`. The code is given below

```
import sys
import os

currentdirectory = os.getcwd()

sys.path.append(currentdirectory+"/packages/regex/Python2/")

from regex import *
```

I am getting following error as `_regex` extension module is not created.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>

    from regex import *

  File "/Users/nilakshi/test_branch/packages/regex/Python2/regex.py", line 387, in <module>

    import _regex_core

  File "/Users/nilakshi/test_branch/packages/regex/Python2/_regex_core.py", line 21, in <module>

    import _regex

ImportError: No module named _regex
```

How do I create `_regex` extension module that can be locally used?
Also, can I create `_regex` extension module file such that I can use the same file in different machines without creating again?

Comment: isn't downloading the package and putting it in the directory kind of the same thing as installing it tho? I mean, all you do when you "install" a module is downloading some python files

Comment: By the way, Python includes [this](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html), in case you really don't want to download nor install anything

Comment: Did you try to run `python setup.py build` to build the extension module without installation?

Comment: You can't just download the package and not compile the C extension. The `regex` module consists of *more than just Python code*.

Comment: @Shinratensei: the `regex` package is *`re` improved*, with much better Unicode support. Sometimes you do need it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah I know but you're missing the point. The only reason somebody wouldn't want to install something would be saving memory, but if you download it anyways, what are you saving? Also, he doesn't specify that he needs the `regex` package, so maybe he'd do well with `re`.

Comment: I don't want use python 'setup.py' build. I want to create achieve for my python code.  All necessary packages required by my python code should be contained in the archive.

Comment: I used 'python setup.py build', did not work